# google analytics api v4 using PHP. Ordering output

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I have this code on google analytics API v4 with PHP.

```
  $eCPM_Adsense = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $eCPM_Adsense->setExpression("ga:adsenseECPM");
  $eCPM_Adsense->setAlias("eCPM Adsense");


    // Create the Ordering.
    $ordering = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_OrderBy();
    $ordering->setFieldName("ga:adsenseECPM");
    $ordering->setOrderType("VALUE");   
    $ordering->setSortOrder("DESCENDING");
```

The Ordering not works for me. Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?   No results? error? incorrect results?

Comment: I see the output correctly, but if I want ordering the items, don't work.

I used this documentations
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#dimensions_and_metrics 

But Here I can't find examples on Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_OrderBy() class

Thank a lot

Answer (score 27, accepted):

the problem is that you need to have the setOrderBys() on the request.  This is not detailed on the API documentation...

an example

```
$ordering = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_OrderBy();
$ordering->setFieldName("ga:pageviews");
$ordering->setOrderType("VALUE");   
$ordering->setSortOrder("DESCENDING");

$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
$request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
$request->setDimensions(array($path));
$request->setMetrics(array($sessions));
$request->setOrderBys($ordering); // note this one!
```

Comment: Ah ok.. it works now!
In fact it is not specified to the API documentation.
It will be usefull at all..
Thanks a lot @andy

Comment: Nice.  Glad to know your working now.  Can you up vote the answer so that others can find it easily?

Answer (score 1):

OrderBy method is not explained well in Google Documentation.
The only example they have in Reporting API v4 is that

```
// Create the Ordering.
$ordering = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_OrderBy();
$ordering->setOrderType("HISTOGRAM_BUCKET");
$ordering->setFieldName("ga:sessionCount");
```

here is an example for getReport($analytics)

```
function getReport($analytics) {

  // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("30daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("yesterday");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:searchUniques");
  $sessions->setAlias("searchKeyword");

  //Create the Dimensions object.
  $searchKeyword = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
  $searchKeyword->setName("ga:searchKeyword");

  // Create order object
  $ordering = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_OrderBy();
  $ordering->setFieldName("ga:searchUniques");
  $ordering->setOrderType("VALUE");   
  $ordering->setSortOrder("DESCENDING"); //There is no "-" usage

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setDimensions(array($searchKeyword));
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));
  $request->setOrderBys($ordering); //Must be added

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}
```

It's also not mentioned under migration documents. Hope It's going to be updated soon.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a library to help you integrate analytics api v4 using php with easy. Take a look at: https://github.com/panakour/google-analytics